# Dart - Model did not stabilize - Component

Tags: dart, angular-dart

i'm expanding angular.dart tutorial for some simple CRUD operations. I'm trying to do nice, smart combobox (dropdown box) that is taking List of KeyValuePairs and returning Selected KeyValyePair.
Unfortunatly i'm getting this error.

```
Model did not stabilize in 10 digests. Last 3 iterations:
itemsMap: collection: Instance of 'KeyValuePair'[null -> 0], Instance of 'KeyValuePair'[null -> 1]...
```

There is code.

dropdown_box.dart

```
    library dropdown_box;

import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'dart:core';
import 'package:tutorial/service/KeyValuePair.dart';
import 'dart:async';


@Component(selector: 'dropdownbox', templateUrl: 'dropdown_box.html', publishAs: 'dropCtrl')
class DropDownComponent {
  // @NgOneWay('items-map')
  // Map<String, String> itemsMap;

  @NgOneWay('items-map')
 List<KeyValuePair> itemsMap;


  @NgTwoWay('selected-keyvalue')
  KeyValuePair selectedKeyValue;

//   void printit(item) {
//    new Future(() {
//      print("${item.value + ' '+ item.key}");
//       SelectedKeyValue = new KeyValuePair(item.key, item.value);
//     });

  String selectedKey;
  void setKeyAsSelected() {

    new Future(() {
      Iterable keyvaluepairs = itemsMap.where((i) => i.key == selectedKey);
      if (keyvaluepairs.length > 0) {
        selectedKeyValue = keyvaluepairs.elementAt(0);
      }
    });

  }

}
```

dropdown_box.html

```
<div class=dropdownbox">
  <select ng-model="selectedKey" ng-change="setKeyAsSelected()">
    <option ng-value=""></option>
    <option ng-repeat="item in itemsMap" ng-value="item.key">
     {{item.value}}
      </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

use in recipe_book.html

```
<dropdownbox items-map="categorieKvList" selected-keyvalue="selectedKV"></dropdownbox>
```

recipe_book.dart (important part only)

```
  KeyValuePair selectedKV;

  List<KeyValuePair> _categorieKvList = new List<KeyValuePair>();
  List<KeyValuePair> get categorieKvList {
    _categorieKvList.clear();
   categories.forEach((f)=>
       _AddToList(f, f));
   return _categorieKvList;
  }

  _AddToList(key, value)
  {
    KeyValuePair kvpair = new KeyValuePair.fromValues(key, value); //new KeyValuePair().AddValues(key, value);
    _categorieKvList.add(kvpair);
  }
```

keyvaluepair.dart

```
library KeyValuePair;

import 'package:angular/angular.dart';

@Injectable()
class KeyValuePair {
  dynamic key;
  dynamic value;

//  AddValues(key, value) {
//    this.key = key;
//    this.value = value;
//  }

  KeyValuePair();
  KeyValuePair.fromValues(dynamic this.key, dynamic this.value);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The getter of `categorieKvList` returns a changed _categorieKvList with new KeyValu pairs every time it is called. This is interpreted by angular as change.

Alter the logic to so _categorieKvList is modified only when its data source (categories) changes.